# Transfer focus to a tab in a Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

In my extension I create a small popup window:

```
"browser_action": {
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
```

and then inject some JavaScript to the page loaded in the active tab.
It is supposed to change the cursor shape and register an 'onclick' event.

It works fine, however, the user needs to click the page/tab twice.
The first click transfers the focus to the page/tab, and only the second click is handled by the onclick handler.
Likewise, the cursor shape (`style.cursor = 'crosshair'`) changes only after the first click.

How can I transfer focus automatically to the tab?
I have tried `chrome.tabs.update({"active":true});` but that does not work.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Stack Overflow",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<!--
 This page is shown when the extension button is clicked, because the
 "browser_action" field in manifest.json contains the "default_popup" key with
 value "popup.html".
 -->
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Question</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>How to transfer focus to the tab?</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({ "file": "page.js" });
    chrome.tabs.update({"active":true});
    return;
});
```

page.js

```
// The cursor is not updated until I click the tab.
document.body.style.cursor = 'crosshair';
document.addEventListener('click', function(){alert('you clicked me')});
```

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. The other question talks about switching tabs, which is not my case. I believe I do not even need `tabs` permission (only `activeTab`).

Comment: ok, goodluck brah :)

Comment: How about you remove the duplicate tag then?

Comment: Looks like this problem may be specific to MacOS. I have just installed my extension on Chrome 57.0.2987.98 for Linux/Gnome 3 and it works the way I expect. The cursor changes immediately to the crosshair shape and the page handles the first click.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found to do this is to call `window.close()` from the popup script once it's set any state necessary for the content script to do its thing.

This will close the popup and transfer focus back to the active tab.